# I have trouble writing data to my database using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

First of all, sorry for the vague title. I am not really sure how to describe this problem in a short way.
Anyway, here is the long version:

I am working on a download manager that will download pdf documents stored in url addresses that are stored in a database table. In the database table I have a column called "Download status". Whenever a new pdf has been downloaded from an url, I want to print "Downloaded" and append it to the "Download Status" column in the table, so that I can see which files were downloaded.

But I cannot get it to work. The program DOES append "Downloaded" to the column, but it does not insert it into the row next to the url that was downloaded. Instead it creates a whole new row of NULLs where it gets placed next to.

example:

Istead of doing this:

http://www..... - Downloaded

it does this:

NULL - Downloaded

Here is the code and what I tried so far.

The download process:

```
                r = requests.get(row[1], allow_redirects=True)
                open(row[0] + '.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)

                print(f"{row[0]} - Downloaded")
                DatabaseReader.cursor_object.execute\
                    ("INSERT INTO GRI_NEW (Download_Status) VALUES ('Downloaded')")
                DatabaseReader.connection_object.commit()
```

UPDATE:

I also tried using UPDATE as suggested by another user, but that didn't do anything.

```
                DatabaseReader.cursor_object.execute \
                    ("UPDATE GRI_NEW SET Download_Status = 'Downloaded' "
                     "WHERE Pdf_Url = %s")
                DatabaseReader.connection_object.commit()
```

I tried putting it into a function too, specifying the row.

```
                def update_download(rowid, status):
                    DatabaseReader.cursor_object.execute \
                        ("UPDATE GRI_NEW SET Download_Status = %s "
                         "WHERE Pdf_Url = %s")
                    DatabaseReader.connection_object.commit()
                update_download(row[1], 'Downloaded')
```

The whole code:

My database reader

```
   import pyodbc

class DatabaseReader:
    # Check drivers
    #for driver in pyodbc.drivers():
        #print(driver)

    # Define server and database
    DRIVER = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    SERVER = '......\MSSQLSERVER01'
    DATABASE = 'TEST_DATABASE'

    # Create connection string
    CONNECTION_STRING = "Driver={driver}; " \
                        "Server={server}; " \
                        "Database={database}; " \
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;" \
        .format(driver=DRIVER, server=SERVER, database=DATABASE)

    # Connect to database
    connection_object: pyodbc.Connection = pyodbc.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)

    # Create cursor object
    cursor_object: pyodbc.Cursor = connection_object.cursor()

        # Fetch records from database
    sql_select = \
        "SELECT Pdf_Url, Download_Status FROM GRI_NEW"
    records = DatabaseReader.cursor_object.execute(sql_select).fetchall()
```

My downloader file.

```
# Function to validate and download URL
def url_validator(row):
    if row:
        # Check if URL in first row is valid
        if validators.url(str(row[0])):
            #print(f"{row[0]} - Url is valid")

            try:
                get = requests.get(row[0], timeout=1)
                if get.status_code == 200:
                    #print(f"{row[0]}: is reachable")

                    # Download the URL

                    r = requests.get(row[1], allow_redirects=True)
                    open(row[0] + '.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
 
                    print(f"{row[0]} - Downloaded")
                    DatabaseReader.cursor_object.execute\
                        ("INSERT INTO GRI_NEW (Download_Status) VALUES ('Downloaded')")
                    DatabaseReader.connection_object.commit()

                else:
                    print(f"{row[0]}: is Not reachable")

            except BaseException as error:
                print('An exception occurred: {}'.format(error))

        else:
            #print(f"{row[0]} - Url is invalid")
            status_report.append(f'{row[0]} - Not Downloaded')
    else:
        #print(f"{row[0]} - Url is invalid")
        status_report.append(f'{row[0]} - Not Downloaded')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)  # Create a multiprocessing Pool
    pool.imap_unordered(url_validator, records)  # process data_inputs iterable with pool
```

Comment: You'll need an UPDATE query instead of an INSERT query if you want to update the row for the particular URL's status. Where does `records` come from?

Comment: Records comes from the database reader file. It holds all the data that is fetched from the database.